# abstract algebra recommended book

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I'm taking abstract algebra in university. My lecturer use Robert Ash notes as lecture notes. But I think that is not enough as very few things are mentioned in the notes. Can anyone recommend a book or note which gives an extensive explanations or give some motivation on why we need to study these things ?

Comment: Look at some of these lists for ideas: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/good-books-for-self-studying-algebra?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49253/requesting-abstract-algebra-book-recommendations?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study?rq=1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78286/casual-book-on-abstract-algebra?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dummit & Foote](http://books.google.com/books/about/Abstract_Algebra.html?id=KJDBQgAACAAJ) is well liked.

Answer (score 0):

I like

First Course in Abstract Algebra (Van Nostrand Reinhold new mathematics library) by P J Higgins (Apr 22, 1975)

of which second hand copies are available on line. He nicely ties in the abstract/general theory  and the concrete.