# Good textbooks for Group,Ring,Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, online-resources

This is in reference to this:[Good abstract algebra books for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study).

I am an undergraduate student in Mathematics.I have studied Introductory courses in Ring Theory and Group Theory.

I would like to study the following courses:

- Group Action,Stabilisers,Cayleys Theorem,Class Equation,Automorphisms,Direct Products,Solvable Groups,Simple Groups in particular $A_n$.
- Field Theory: Algebraic Extension,Algebraic Closure,Finite Fields.
- Galois Extension,Cyclotomic Extensions ,Solvability of radicals.
- Ring Theory:Euclidean Domain,Principal Ideal Domain,UFD.

I want a book  which can be used as a textbook

I checked out the above references which mainly asked to study Dummit Foote.

But I found Dummit & Foote too broad.Its fine as reference though.Lang is quite tough.Artin does not cover all the topics and is more intended towards Geometry.Gallian is nice but cant be used as a textbook.

I want a book like "Bartle and Sherbert of Real Anlaysis" which can be used as a textbook and

What are some

Comment: Try Herstein's  "Topics in Algebra" as suggested in the comments section of the question referred to in your link.

Comment: You can try Aluffi’s “Algebra, Chapter 0”.

Comment: Im starting now the book of Aluffi, it seems better that many other classic texts

Comment: Jacobson's Basic Algebra