# Can one make a group out of these transcendental points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, transcendental-numbers

Can one make a group out of a set of transcendental points including the identity point? Here, $\Bbb A$ represents any non-zero algebraic number. I'm working with real numbers.

My set consists of points $X=\{(e^{\Bbb {-A}},e^{\Bbb {-A}}), (e^{\Bbb {A}}, e^{\Bbb A}),(1,1)\}.$ I have the identity element as $(1,1)$ and I've checked that associativity holds and commutativity holds. I have the binary operation as multiplication.

By Lindemann-Weirstrauss, $e^\alpha$ is transcendental whenever $\alpha$ is non-zero algebraic.

To combine elements I take the Cartesian product of the first two points in the set defined above. That is, $(e^{\Bbb {-A}},e^{\Bbb {-A}})\times(e^{\Bbb {A}}, e^{\Bbb A}).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation, a map $G\times G\to G$, satisfying certain axioms. In your case, you have a 3-element set $G$ (which you call $X$). Your binary operation $*$ is the coordinate-wise multiplication. In order for your operation to be a map $G\times G\to G$, you have to have:
$$
(e^A, e^A) * (e^A, e^A) \in G\Rightarrow 
e^A\cdot e^A\in \{1, e^A, e^{-A}\}. 
$$
Thus, either $e^{2A}=1$, or $e^{2A}=e^A$, or $e^{2A}=e^{-A}$. In each of these cases, $A=0$, i.e. $e^A=1$. In other words, the only time your $G$ with the given binary operation is a group is when $G=\{(1,1)\}$ and $e^A=1$, i.e. is not a transcendental number.

Few more things:

1. The last paragraph in your question is very unclear since in a group there is no "combination" operation.
2. Your question "Can one make a group out of a set of transcendental points including the identity point?" has the affirmative answer: Take any transcendental number $\alpha$ (real or complex, does not matter) and consider the subgroup $\langle \alpha\rangle=\{\alpha^n: n\in {\mathbb Z}\}$ in ${\mathbb C}^\times$ generated by $\alpha$. Then  $\langle \alpha\rangle$ with the binary operation given by the usual multiplication is a group, consisting only of transcendental numbers (and $1$).
3. On a side note, this algebra question is better than the topology questions you asked earlier. My suggestion is to pick up an algebra textbook with exercises (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study) for suggestions) and solve them one-by-one. Then do the same with a topology textbook, say, Munkres.