# Introductory Analysis and Groups textbooks

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am doing an introductory analysis and groups course next semester and I have a couple of questions about books. The course textbook required is 'An introduction to Analysis' by W R Wade. Can anyone tell me if/when a new edition is expected and if not, what the current edition of the book is? I tried googling but couldn't see anything.

Perhaps just for self study, what introductory analysis/groups textbooks would you recommend, that you have perhaps found good when you did a similar course etc..

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard of an introductory course on those two topics together.

Comment: @Tobias I suspect, but I could be wrong, that OP is talking about two separate introductory classes, and seeking separate books, but it is not at all clear.

Comment: I meant two separate books, one on Analysis and one on Groups. Apologies.

Comment: For groups, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/introductory-group-theory-textbook.

Comment: @Ihf That's good. I'am  a little confused though - are they talking about graduate level courses?

Comment: I believe Rotman's book is better for a graduate course, but the rest of them are aimed at undergraduate students.