# group theory for non-mathematicians

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

A very smart non-mathematician friend is looking to learn about groups, and I was wondering if people might have suggestions (this is NOT a duplicate of [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/introductory-group-theory-textbook) since a textbook is not what I am looking for, at least not at first).

Comment: Have a look at the Numberphile video series on youtube. They have a lot of videos for non-mathematicians who are interested!

Comment: @Ed_4434 Thanks! I will check it out...

Comment: Your non-mathematician friend might find the book *Abel's Proof*, by Peter Pesic, worth a look.

Comment: Why exactly do they want to learn about groups? If it is for an application (e.g. point group theory in inorganic chemistry) then it might be best to go for a presentation that is interlaced with the application, rather than a standard mathematical presentation.

Comment: Compared with most advanced mathematics, basic group theory is not very difficult.  Your friend might be surprised at how much success she has with a regular undergraduate textbook.  The John Fraleigh book is very readable.

Comment: @Ian My friend is interested on general principles (she is actually a film-maker!)

Comment: A book with a lot of group theory which is related to particle physics and that i like a lot is ''Lie Groups in Particle Physics'' by Georgi

Comment: If you round to the nearest hour, people use an Abelian additive group of order $12$ or $24$ every day when working with time. That's secretly everyone's first group.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: unless you count the order-2 group containing yourself and your reflection in a mirror :-)

Comment: Take a look at [Introduction to Group Theory](http://dogschool.tripod.com). It's pretty gentle, and doesn't assume much prior knowledge, except some familiarity with basic algebra notation.

Comment: Most textbooks on introductory group theory don't require any particular mathematical prerequisites beyond being comfortable with abstraction and proofs.

Answer (score 10):

*Groups and Symmetry: A Guide to **Discovering Mathematics***, by David W. Farmer.

The highlighted title may convince that it assumes not too much mathematics for the learner. It is very little book, not of the type *Definition-Theorem-Proof*.

At least (in on-line preview) I don't find a single concrete mathematical statement, but always beautiful pictures and only that.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try *The Fascination of Groups* by Budden.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend the Marcus du Sautoy's book: [**Finding Moonshine** : Mathematician's Journey Through Symmetry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0007214626)
[image]

He is also the author of [The Music of the Primes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062064010).

Comment: Read this. Don't think the author knew how to dumb it down without really dumbing it down.

Answer (score 4):

Two books not yet mentioned that the OP might want to consider are:

[**Groups in the New Mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JBZYV0) by Irving Adler (1967)

[**Groups and Their Graphs**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088385614X) by Israel Grossman and Wilhelm Magnus (1964)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Carter's *Visual Group Theory*. It makes heavy use of pictures and diagrams (hence the name) and I found it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read, Simon Singh's Fermat's Last Theorem. http://simonsingh.net/books/fermats-last-theorem/

It starts with the introduction to simple problem, solutions. And entire history as it evolves to solve the problem surrounding group theory. And then into advanced theory.

Comment: Ahhh.. I see "-1" on the answer. Care to explain why? I thought Simon Singh was a good start for a non-mathematician.