# Book on finite group theory, containing a sufficient number of examples

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, book-recommendation

I read M.Isaacs book on finite group theory now and I find it quite interesting and well written. But also I feel that there are not enough examples (for me) in this book.

Maybe there is another book wich can be used to complement Isaacs book which contain enough examples? Or maybe there are resources, where one can find interesting and demonstrative examples concerning finite groups?

Comment: See if this helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/introductory-group-theory-textbook

Comment: Last year Serre just wrote a new book on finite groups, he's one of the best writer in mathematics. The two last chapters are about finite subgroup of $\rm{GL}_n$ and group of small order.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys!

Comment: I agree with @NicolasHemelsoet that it's always worth checking out Serre.  The specific book is [Serre - Finite groups: An introduction](http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/books/items/00000475), also sold through the [AMS](http://bookstore.ams.org/inpr-100).  There is an [MAA review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/finite-groups-an-introduction), which suggests that it may not be at the level for someone looking for an introduction to group theory.  (I cannot tell whether that describes the poster.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not try one of the following:

John S. Rose, *[A Course on Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books/about/A_Course_on_Group_Theory.html?id=pYk6AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)*

Derek J.S. Robinson, *[A Course in The Theory of Groups](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zLfkBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmn7DjwL7YAhVDalAKHU4OAqwQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&f=false)*

Dummit and Foote, *[Abstract Algebra](http://zeth.ciencias.uchile.cl/~cortiz/Apuntes/ebooks/Abstract%20algebra%20-%20Dummit%20and%20Foote.pdf)*.

Each of these books has a lot of good examples and exercises!

Comment: Second the vote for Dummitt & Foote (+1). It covers a lot more than finite groups, but is really an example-based text that is also very rigorous. Highly recommend.

Comment: Thank you, Nicky. I knew about the  DF book, but somehow underestimated it. But in DF book there are no such deep topics as in Isaacs book (for example Chermak-Delgado measure) and so less or more non-trivial examples one forced to look elsewhere.

Comment: It's too small to try suggesting the edit, but, as @rogerl politely [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591400/book-on-finite-group-theory-containing-a-sufficiently-number-of-examples/2591910#comment5350740_2591673), you probably want to change the spelling of 'Foote' (from 'Foot').

Comment: @Lspice, Certainly a "misstep" :-) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @NickyHekster, well, I guess I put Foote in your mouth.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

*Groups: A Path to Geometry* by R.P. Burn is an introduction to group theory that consists entirely of examples, problems and solutions.

*Schaum's Outline of Group Theory* by B. Baumslag contains lots of examples and problems with solutions.

*Adventures in Group Theory: Rubik's Cube, Merlin's Machine, and Other Mathematical Toys* by David Joyner is built around a series of concrete examples and applications of groups.

Answer (score 4):

A very literal answer:  Michael Weinstein has a book called [Examples of groups](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL6917375W/Examples_of_groups).

Comment: Thank you, I never hear about this book.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer, the following books for group theory in order.

1. Abstract Algebra by "Dummit & Foote", Wiley publication.
2. A course in Abstract Algebra By, "khanna and Bhambri", vikas publication.
3. Contemporary Abstract Algebra By "Gallian".

If you want, classic text with lots of examples prefer, (1) and (3) and if you want lots of solved examples prefer (2). In (2) there are lots of solved examples, covering all topics, groups, rings, fields, In fact on linear transformations too.

Comment: Thank you, Akash! Despite the third book seems to be elementary, there is a quite useful section suggested readings!