# Good introductory textbook for group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I am beginning to learn group theory (specifically finite groups) and I’m wondering which textbooks can help me.

So any suggestions for introductory texts?

Comment: Rotman's is pretty good.

Comment: While I wrote an answer, this will probably be closed as either a duplicate or primarily opinion based, in fact I should probably vote to close myself: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25506/90543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few (very) good textbooks on finite groups out there. My favourite is Isaacs' "Finite Group Theory", but I wouldn't recommend it as a first textbook. Robinson's "A Course in the Theory of Groups" and Rose's "A Course on Group Theory" are both excellent.

In my opinion, though, the best book to read as a first when it comes to group theory is Smith's and Tabachnikova's "Topics in Group Theory".

Answer (score 4):

My introduction to groups (and algebra in general) was I.N. Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*. It begins with the theory of groups (covering what I would regard as the essential basics), but also covers rings, fields, vector spaces, and linear transformations. It's short, well written, and has a *lot* of good exercises.

I also really like Michael Artin's *Algebra*, which again is an introductory algebra textbook, but it includes quite a lot of good material on groups. I would say it's a bit more comprehensive than Herstein, and also very well written of course.

Lastly, I've gotten a lot of mileage out of Milne's course notes, which between them cover almost all of the algebra I've ever needed to know. It's been a while since I've read his [group theory notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html), but they're free on his website, so it's worth checking out.