# What are some good books on group theory?

Tags: group-theory

I want to self-study group theory.

Does anyone have good recommendations for me?

Comment: gallian........

Comment: Do you know any group theory already? How mathematically mature are you?

Comment: I don't know much about group theory, but I think I am mathematically mature enough for a "rigorous" book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/introductory-group-theory-textbook

Comment: If you haven't taken an abstract algebra course, it might be a good idea to grab an introductory undergrad text on that, such as Artin's  *Algebra*,  and read it's section on groups first.  Plus such a text will also contain a general variety of applications of groups, for instance to Galois theory and to combinatorics (see the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem)).

Comment: Although this can probably also be said of a groups-specific text, lol

Comment: For me, Gallian's Abstract Algebra text was a joy in the undergraduate course I took on the subject. Also, Fraleigh's text was a nice bridge for me between undergraduate and graduate level abstract algebra.